# Trying to extract JSON data from an URL into Jupyter?

Tags: python, json, extract, jupyter

Trying to extract data from the website below:

https://gbfs.fordgobike.com/gbfs/gbfs.json

Comment: Transition to Python 3, you mean IDE? You should have a look at the request library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import requests

url = 'https://gbfs.fordgobike.com/gbfs/gbfs.json'
data = requests.get(url).json()

print(data)
```

Number of rides available, try this:

```
import requests

url = 'https://gbfs.fordgobike.com/gbfs/en/station_status.json'
data = requests.get(url).json()

d = {s['station_id']:s['num_bikes_available'] for s in data['data']['stations']}

print(d)
```

Result:

```
{'10': 28,
 '100': 14,
 '101': 8,
 '102': 22,
 '103': 0,
 '104': 0,
 '105': 5,
 '106': 1,
 '107': 14,
 '108': 1,
 '109': 2,
 '11': 16,
 '110': 10,
 '112': 13,
 '113': 5,
 '114': 9,
  ...
```

Comment: Yes, I was also trying to pull up the number of rides per station.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you.  I did not know the correct syntax.  I appreciate your advice.